# How to properly use SSH as a VPN?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ssh, vpn, proxy

I have been dealing with extreme internet censorship in my country for the past month.

I tried everything on my Ubuntu VPS including OpenVPN, open connect and then finally [V2Ray](https://github.com/v2fly/v2ray-core)+WS worked for a few days, and then it stopped. I don't know how to troubleshoot and know what and how exactly they blocked, but I can access my VPS.

So is there anything you can help me with here?

At last, I tried SSH and it seems it’s almost working. I am just using:

```
putty.exe -ssh -D port -N server
```

And then using Windows applications on socks(`127.0.0.1` and `-D` port) seems to be working; although Chrome uses Windows 10 proxy and when I use the proxy there it just does not allow the internet to the apps.

So here are a few questions:

1. Using CMD for SSH is easier than PuTTY but I could not connect to a proxy like that. Does it pass the internet like that?
2. It's really complicated to set up all the devices at home or even for friends like this. Is there a better way to do so using SSH?

Update: this guide helped me a lot and now there is no internet blocking on my PC. but still how to provide it for others? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FinTVVi7LT4&ab_channel=HostRoundLLC

Update2: the best thing I could come up with is to use Connectify on windows to share my OpenVPN connection. but still, need a good easy solution for mobile devices.

Comment: consider TOR if its an option for you. there has been a lot of effort put in to make it easier to set up, and it's focused more on Internet access than SSH (which is really a remote administration protocol). May work better for your usecase. https://www.torproject.org/

Comment: oh TOR does not work at all. was not working for years here. its really big internet censorship